# How to show that $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ are simple?

Tags: lie-algebras

We defined a Lie algebra to be simple, if it has no proper Lie ideals and is not $k$ (the ground field). We have the proposition that $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ are simple $\mathbb{R}$-Lie algebras, and $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is also simple as a $\mathbb{C}$-Lie algebra. We have shown the proposition for the case $n=2$ using an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple.

How would I show the statement for general $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I suspect there's a way to use induction, but don't see how that would work. Also, I have no idea how I would generalize and apply the idea with the $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple to higher dimensions. I can't even just do the case $n=3$. How do I generalize?

Comment: A link has been provided on a duplicate thread: https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/~plyung/simplicity_sln.pdf

Comment: @darijgrinberg Unfortunately the links says "access forbidden!".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Make it http://web.archive.org/web/20210507034553/https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/~plyung/simplicity_sln.pdf then.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Indeed, there it is - thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a direct proof that $\mathfrak{sl}(n,K)$ is a simple Lie algebra for any field $K$ of characteristic zero, which just uses Lie brackets of traceless matrices to show that a nontrivial ideal $J$ must be $\mathfrak{sl}(n,K)$ itself, see [6.4](https://books.google.at/books?id=SuR5OAgxyDIC&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=sl(n)+is+a+simpel+lie+algebra&source=bl&ots=qhBzhr15Vw&sig=HB11b2vZ6gB1XcZxyQang2HPtog&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxnvPkq47KAhVEthQKHbHSAOcQ6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=sl(n)%20is%20a%20simpel%20lie%20algebra&f=false) in the book "Naive Lie Theory". This works uniformly for all $n\ge 2$. For a proof using a bit more theory, see Lemma $1.3$ [here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~crystal/LA2010/lecture_7.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for the references. I looked up the elementary proof and it is rather straight-forward. I am a bit confused though: We never really make use of bilinearity (over $K$) of the Lie bracket. Does this mean the proof given in "Naive Lie Theory" works for $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ as both $\mathbb{R}$- and $\mathbb{C}$-Lie algebra?

Comment: For this question see "real forms", or "complexification" and "realification" of simple Lie algebras, see $2.2.1.9$ [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjRvdG9oJDKAhWKOhQKHZj0AmAQFggjMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.itp.uni-hannover.de%2F~giulini%2Fpapers%2FLieRep.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFQZAyKRK6Vw6XDjX05Pz_IoEiPzQ&sig2=mW-279Duz_Ji3pxsxadR9g&bvm=bv.110151844,d.d24). You do not need an extra proof for $\mathbb{sl}(n)$, this follows from general principles.

Comment: I'll have a look at your reference as soon as possible. What exactly do you mean by $\mathbb{sl}(n)$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user302234 It means $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$, see the last link. Did you had time to look at the reference in the meantime?