# $\mathfrak{so}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is a simple Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{so}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ be all the matrices in the form of $g=\begin{pmatrix}A & B\\
C & -A^T\end{pmatrix}$, where $B$ and $C$ are skew symmetric and $A,B,C$ are  $n\times n$ matrices. Show that $\mathfrak{so}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is a simple Lie algebra.

By some simple calculation I can deduce that if $r$ is a non-zero ideal of $\mathfrak{so}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ containing an element in the form $\begin{pmatrix}A & B\\
C & -A^T\end{pmatrix}$ then there must be an element in $r$ such that $B\neq 0,C\neq 0$. Also the elements $\begin{pmatrix}A & 0\\
0 & -A^T\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0 & \pm B\\
\pm C & 0\end{pmatrix}$ are in $r$. But how can I go ahead?

Comment: Can you work out its Dynkin diagram and show that it is connected?

Comment: Yes. But I have not studied the equivalence of the connectness of the Dynkin diagram and the simplicity. So I want some direct proof.

Comment: Don't you need to assume $n \ge 3$?

Comment: Yes, it is.@QiaochuYuan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the hints by Dietrich Burde, I can give a sketch of proof. First, for $gl_S(n)=\{x\in gl(n)|x^TS+xS=0\}$, we can show that $gl_S(n)\cong gl_T(n)$ if there exists a complex invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^TSP=T$(the isomorphism given by $A\mapsto P^{-1}AP$). Then we observe that there exists such a $P$ satisfying $P^T\begin{pmatrix}0 & I\\ I & 0\end{pmatrix}P=I_{2n}$. Hence we turn to show that the space of $2n\times2n$ complex skew-symmetric matrices is a simple Lie algebra. Then using the method(just some calculation) given by chapter 6.5 of John Stillwell's book Naive Lie Theory, we can prove it. Of course, as Qiaochu mentioned, $n$ has to be more than or equal $3$.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to show directly that $\mathfrak{so}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is a simple Lie algebra for $n\ge 3$. One starts with a non-zero ideal $I$ and applying successively adjoint operators one shows that all basis vectors have to lie in $I$, so that $I=\mathfrak{so}(2n,\mathbb{C})$. Hence the algebra is simple. This is proved in detail in the book "naive Lie theory" by John Stillway, see the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598356/how-to-show-that-mathfraksl-n-mathbbr-and-mathfraksl-n-mathbbc?rq=1).

However, there are much more elegant ways to show this, e.g., by using the *Killing form* 
$$\kappa (x,y)=tr(ad(x)ad(y)).$$

It is easy to see that the Killing form of $\mathfrak{so}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is a non-zero multiple of the trace form and is non-degenerate. Then it follows that $\mathfrak{so}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is semisimple. Since the root system for $n>2$ is indecomposable, it is also simple.

Comment: And to connect to key-words, the implication that non-degenerate Killing form implies (semi-) simplicity is "Cartan's criterion".

Comment: But the non-degeneration of the Killing form only implies the semi-simplicity. How can I deduce the simplicity?

Comment: Fixed. And no need for more effort, the direct proof (John Stillwell) is also fine.

Comment: But how to identify my space with the $\mathfrak{so}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ in John Stillway's book which is the space of all $2n\times 2n$ skew symmetric matrices?The linear isomorphism $a\mapsto Ba$ does not preserve the Lie bracket, where $B$ is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & I\\
I & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: This is explained in books on Lie algebras, e.g., in the book of K. Erdmann and M. Wildon, page $33$.

Comment: How can I get this Killing form, it is hard to compute for general n.

Comment: @Goldmund No, it is not hard at all to compute - see for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form).