# restriction diagonalizable operator is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> If $T:V\to V$ is diagonalizable and $S \subset V$ is a $T$-invariant subspace, I have to show that $T|_{S}$ is diagonalizable, but without using the minimal polynomial.

I can not think how to do it without using the minimal polynomial.

Thanks

Comment: I actually think it's easier without the minimal polynomial. This is hardly formal, but think of $S$ as corresponding to a part of the diagonal matrix. A part of a diagonal matrix is still a diagonal matrix. Making this into a formal statement is quite straight forward, in terms of kernels, basis vectors, transition matrices, or really whatever you choose.

Comment: i can do it: take ${\v_{1},..v_{p} \}$ basis of $S$. after complete this basis with eigenvectors: $B={\v_{1},..v_{p}, u_{p+1},...,u_{n} \}$ , and make matrix change basis with basis $D$ with all eigenvectors. And the block in matrix change is the matrix change for $T|_{S}$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diagonalizable transformation restricted to an invariant subspace is diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62338/diagonalizable-transformation-restricted-to-an-invariant-subspace-is-diagonaliza)

Comment: @PatrickR yes look fine