# Minimal polynomial and diagonalization of a block diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

Let $A \in \mathbb C^{m\times m}$ and $B \in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$, and let $C=\begin{pmatrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & B\\
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb C^{(m+n)\times (m+n)}$.

1. Calculate the minimal polynomial of $C$ based on the minimal of $A$ and the minimal of $B$.
2. Prove that $C$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A$ and $B$ are.

The attempt at a solution

I have no idea how to prove 1). For 2) I got stuck in a lot of parts:

$\Leftarrow$ If $C$ is diagonalizable, then $C=P^{-1}DP$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Somehow, I must construct from D two diagonal matrices $D_1 \in \mathbb C^{m\times m}$ and $D_2 \in  \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ and two invertible matrices $Q$ and $S$ so that $A=Q^{-1}D_1Q$ and $B=S^{-1}D_2S$, I don't know how to construct all these matrices.

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable, so $A=Q^{-1}D_1Q$ and $B=S^{-1}D_2S$, with both $D_1$ and $D_2$ diagonal matrices. My guess is $C$ can be written as

$\pmatrix{Q^{-1}&0\\ 0&S^{-1}}\pmatrix{D_1&0\\ 0&D_2}\pmatrix{Q&0\\ 0&S}$.

Now, I would have to prove that $\pmatrix{Q^{-1}&0\\ 0&S^{-1}}\pmatrix{Q&0\\ 0&S}=Id_{m+n}$ and that $C=\pmatrix{Q^{-1}&0\\ 0&S^{-1}}\pmatrix{D_1&0\\ 0&D_2}\pmatrix{Q&0\\ 0&S}$ in order to show $C$ is diagonalizable.

I would appreciate help in all these points where I am stuck and any suggestion or hint with regard to 1.

Comment: Although I just answered this question, I am going to close this question as a duplicate that I came across; to improve navigation on this site. Even if the linked question does not explicitly ask about 1), answers for that that part are provided there too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Notice that if $P$ is a polynomial then
   $$P(C)=\begin{pmatrix}
   P(A) & 0 \\
   0 & P(B)\\
   \end{pmatrix}$$
   so we see that $P$ annihilates $C$ if and only if it annihilates $A$ and $B$. If we denote $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ the minimal polynomial of $A$ and $B$ respectively then the polynomial $P=\pi_A\lor \pi_B$ annihilates $C$
   so $\pi_C$ divides $P$ and conversely since $\pi_C$ annihilates $C$ so it annihilates $A$ and $B$ so $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ divides $\pi_C$ and then $P$ divides $\pi_C$. We conclude that
   $$\pi_C=\pi_A\lor \pi_B$$
2. $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable if and only if $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ have  simple roots, if and only if $\pi_A\lor \pi_B=\pi_C$ has simple roots, if and only if $C$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Is it always true that if a polynomial $P$ of a diagonal block matrix give us zeros out of the diagonal?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the field is $\Bbb C$ is irrelevant here, so I'll just write $F$.

You have here that the obvious direct sum decomposition $F^{m+n}\cong F^m\oplus F^n$ is stable under the linear operator$~T$ defined by the matrix $C$ (that is, each of the summands is mapped into itself by$~T$), and the restrictions of $T$ to those summands have matrices $A$ respectively $B$. Therefore, for any polynomial$~P$ one has $P[C]=0$ if and only if both $P[A]=0$ and $P[B]=0$ (the restrictions of $P[T]$ to both summands must vanish). The latter means $P$ is a common multiple of the minimal polynomials $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$ of $A,B$, respectively. Then $\mu_C=\operatorname{lcm}(\mu_A,\mu_B)$.

So for part 1 I just repeated the answer by Sami Ben Romdhane. But for part 2, you do not really need to use part 1 (even though that is a natural thing to do if you know that diagonalisability can be read off from the minimal polynomials), provided you know instead that the restriction of a diagonalisable operator$~T$ to a $T$-stable subspace is always diagonalisable, or even the weaker result that this holds for a subspace that is $T$-stable and has a $T$-stable complementary subspace, in other words for a summand in a $T$-stable direct sum decomposition of the space. These facts of course also follow by the minimal polynomial characterisation, but they can be proved directly as well, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/78090/18880) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/956984/18880).

Now for 2. one direction is easy: if both $A$ and $B$ are diagonalisable, then bases of eigenvectors for them obviously lift to $F^{m+n}$ to produce a basis of eigenvectors for $C$. For the converse the cited result applies: $C$ is diagonalisable, so restrictions of$~T$ to the $T$-stable summands of $F^{m+n}\cong F^m\oplus F^n$ are also diagonalisable, whence $A$ and $B$ are.

The proof of the cited result a gave under the second link concretely gives: the projections of $F^{m+n}$ onto the summands commutes with $T$ (you can see this directly), so the projection of an eigenspace for$~\lambda$ of$~C$ is contained in the eigenspace for$~\lambda$ of$~A$ respectively of$~B$ (or it is $\{0\}$ if there is no such eigenspace); moreover since the sum of all such eigenspaces is all of $F^{m+n}$, the sum of their projections is all of $F^m$ respectively of $F^n$, so $A,B$ are diagonalisable.

Your approach with concrete matrices is certainly not the easiest way (it rarely is for such problems), but one can describe how the above gives you your matrices $Q,S$; I will put the inverses on the other side however (so $C=PDP^{-1}$ so that the columns of the conjugating matrix give a basis of eigenvectors. For each eigenvalue$~\lambda$ of $C$, take the set of $k$ corresponding columns of$~P$ (which form a basis of the eigenspace for $\lambda$) and separate it into the first $m$ rows and the final $n$ rows. These $m\times k$ and $n\times k$ matrices have ranks $r_1,r_2$ with $r_1+r_2=k$, and selecting $r_1$ independent columns from the first part and $r_2$ independent columns form the second part (one can choose complementary sets of columns) gives you bases for the eigenspaces for$~\lambda$ of $A$ respectively$~b$, and thereby contributions to the matrices $Q,S$, respectively.