# Toral subalgebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

In the proof that a Toral subalgebra $T$ of a semisimple Lie algebra $L$ is abelian, one argues that if $x\in  T$ is ad-simple ($ad_x:L\to L$ is diagonalizable), the restriction $ad_x|_T:T\to T$ is also diagonalizable. Why this is true? I can follow the rest of he argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an instance of a more general fact from linear algebra:

> Let $T : V \to V$ be a linear map, with $U \subseteq V$ a
>   $T$-invariant subspace, so that $T(U)\subseteq U$. Then $T_{\big \vert
> U}$ is diagonalisable whenever $T$ is.

You can find multiple proofs of this fact here:

[Diagonalizable transformation restricted to an invariant subspace is diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62338/diagonalizable-transformation-restricted-to-an-invariant-subspace-is-diagonaliza)

---

Note that in our case, that $T$ is an invariant subspace under $\operatorname{ad}_x$ for each $x \in T$ is precisely the condition that $T$ is a subalgebra of $L$.